# VB.NET 'Char' values cannot be converted to 'Integer'

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have converted the C# code to VB.NET and getting following error. Is there anyway to make it work?

First Error

> VB.NET 'Char' values cannot be converted to 'Integer'. Use
>   'Microsoft.VisualBasic.AscW' to interpret a character as a Unicode
>   value or 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Val' to interpret it as a digit.

```
charValue = text(System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(charIndex), charIndex - 1))
```

> Complete Function Code

```
Public Shared Function embedText(text As String, bmp As Bitmap) As Bitmap
        Dim charValue As Integer = 0
charValue = text(System.Math.Max(System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(charIndex), charIndex - 1))


                        Select Case pixelElementIndex Mod 3
                            Case 0
                                If True Then
                                    If state__1 = State.Hiding Then
                                        ' the rightmost bit in the character will be (charValue % 2)
                                        ' to put this value instead of the LSB of the pixel element
                                        ' just add it to it
                                        ' recall that the LSB of the pixel element had been cleared
                                        ' before this operation
                                        R += charValue Mod 2

                                        ' removes the added rightmost bit of the character
                                        ' such that next time we can reach the next one
                                        charValue /= 2
                                    End If
                                End If
                                Exit Select
                            Case 1
                                If True Then
                                    If state__1 = State.Hiding Then
                                        G += charValue Mod 2

                                        charValue /= 2
                                    End If
                                End If
                                Exit Select
                            Case 2
                                If True Then
                                    If state__1 = State.Hiding Then
                                        B += charValue Mod 2

                                        charValue /= 2
                                    End If

                                    bmp.SetPixel(j, i, Color.FromArgb(R, G, B))
                                End If
                                Exit Select
                        End Select

                        pixelElementIndex += 1

                        If state__1 = State.Filling_With_Zeros Then
                            ' increment the value of zeros until it is 8
                            zeros += 1
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
            Next

            Return bmp
        End Function

' convert the character value from int to char
                            Dim c As Char = CChar(charValue)
```

Second Error

> Type Expected

```
Application.Run(New Project1())
```

Help me to run out of these errors.

Comment: Well, the error message gives you two possible options. It sounds like you probably want `AscW` in this case.

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you help me out with this by changing code?

Comment: Not really, given that you've only shown one line of code without any variable declarations etc. Please show a [mcve] and include what you've *tried* to fix the problem, given the error message.

Comment: try, http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?597117-RESOLVED-Char-values-cannot-be-converted-to-Short-Use-Microsoft-VisualBasic-AscW-to-int

Comment: @JonSkeet Uploaded the function code. If i change code adding Asc, ArrayOutofbound exception is throwed.

Comment: That's now a *huge* amount of code. Again, please reduce it to a [mcve].

Comment: @JonSkeet Now? Is that sufficient? and Adding val returns same Exception Arrayoutofrange.

Comment: No, that's still 59 lines of code. I believe you could demonstrate the problem in a complete program (not just a single function) in *significantly* less code... like about 15 lines, if that. Learning to reduce the scope of a problem is a significant skill in software engineering.

Answer (score 2):

Try what the first error message is saying:

create an integer type say

```
Dim intValue As Integer
```

then pass your char value to it

```
intValue = Asc(charValue)
```

or

```
intValue = AscW(charValue)
```

And for the second options you might want to try this

```
intValue = Val(charValue)
```

Comment: Do as Jon Skeet is saying, so maybe consider using intValue = AscW(charValue)

Comment: Returning arrayoutofrange exception :(